# Linking SDL2 emits countless linking errors on OSX

Tags: c, macos, linker, sdl, sdl-2

I have this super simple SDL2 executable:

```
#include <SDL.h>

int main(void)
{
    SDL_Texture* t;
    SDL_DestroyTexture(t);
}
```

I try to compile it like this:

```
clang++ $(sdl2-config --cflags --libs) foo.cc
```

This grants me with a barrage of Linking errors, which all have to do with Objective-C and Apple Libraries. I can do the same with `SDL_Surface* s; SDL_DestroySurface(s);` and it won't emit these errors.

I have found out that I can solve this problem by using `$(sdl2-config --static-libs)`. But I'm pretty sure, I shouldn't need to use this. After all shouldn't the SDL2 library already be linked to them? Why is it only appearing with SDL_Texture, but not with SDL_Surface? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I don't know why I got the downvote. Here I have a small sample of the linking errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_AudioObjectAddPropertyListener", referenced from:
      _COREAUDIO_Init in libSDL2.a(SDL_coreaudio.o)
      _COREAUDIO_OpenDevice in libSDL2.a(SDL_coreaudio.o)
  "_AudioObjectGetPropertyData", referenced from:
      _COREAUDIO_OpenDevice in libSDL2.a(SDL_coreaudio.o)
      _device_unplugged in libSDL2.a(SDL_coreaudio.o)
      _build_device_list in libSDL2.a(SDL_coreaudio.o)
  "_AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize", referenced from:
  (...)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are failing to link against the `CoreAudio` framework.

You'll need to add this to your linker command line:

```
-framework CoreAudio.framework
```

Comment: But shouldn't the SDL2 library already link against `CoreAudio` (and others)? Why do I have to do it? I don't use any CoreAudio functions (as you can see above).

Comment: @hgiesel No; it's a static library.  You need to configure Xcode/Cmake/whatever to link against any required libraries when linking the final executable.  It's always been that way.  You have to do it as SDL is using CoreAudio for it's audio therefore you have to provide the library for it.

Comment: Even SDL itself [discourages static linking](https://wiki.libsdl.org/Installation). And CoreAudio isn't a static library, as there is `CoreAudio.dylib` file inside `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Resources/BridgeSupport`. I still don't get why I need to do this.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about discourages static linking as you are supplying SDL in static library form.  A static library is simply a collection of object file so can you can think of them as just being compiled source files.  Now if you use something from another library, you need to link against that library, and so it will depend how that library is presented to you.  In this case SDL have used CoreAudio and CoreAudio is a framework and hence my answer.  There might be other libraries you need to supply as well (OpenGL, for example).

Comment: Yes my confusion resulted from me thinking, that the `-l` option used shared libraries, when I also just realized that I linked against a `.a` static library. I have both files `libSDL2.a` and `libSDL2.dylib` and currently try to figure out how to use one over the other. I still have to learn a lot.

Comment: Okay, I finally got it by writing the name of the whole library like this: `clang++ -I/usr/local/include/SDL2 /usr/local/lib/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib test.cc -o main`. Thanks for bearing with me!

Comment: Hello I am having the same problem but I am compiling with g++. I cannot find the CoreAudio.framework: is it a folder or file? What should it contain?
I have something like SDL2.framework which is a folder contains a subfolder with makes. I tried to run your command with this framework but it is not working